# Deploying angular project & python services on AWS

Tags: python, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We have an angularJS project which uses python web services.
As of now we have pushed both the codes on AWS EC2 instance.

And running following commands to make it up forever:

```
nohup grunt serve & (for angular project)
nohup python Sample.py & (for python services)
```

Whenever any code changes are made we git pull it and again run above commands.
I know this approach cannot be used for Production as Grunt should be only used for development

Can someone suggest best way to streamline the process right from the servers to deployment?

Comment: Use a webserver: Apache, nginx, ...(many others)...

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is push the code after building and use forever to run your node project, so take if you take pull you dont need to run command again. the only case when you need to run command again is when your index page has some changes.

make sure you run your app behind a web server.